# A large percentage of my traffic originates from my own website's IP address

Tags: traffic, ip-address, statistics, bandwidth

I've been going through my [webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/) stats for the past few months, and on a month to month basis I have noticed this trend.

A very high percentage (usually around 20% of traffic by KBytes) belongs to my own website's IP. I have the following two questions:

1. Is this normal - or something irregular?
2. Is there something I can do to mitigate the volume?

Comment: That's interesting. Are you using any uptime monitoring software, like monit, zabbix, naggios, etc.?

Comment: I am using Pingdom, and I'm sitting at 99.5% uptime. Looking further into the logs, it seems like something is doing a GET call on my Logo every 5 to 10 seconds on average. Definitely seems to be the culprit. I think the question can be marked for closure, I'm not sure how relevant it'll be to others.

Comment: @moose As indicated in your comment, I'm closing this since you've determined the issue is specific to your site (and so users don't continue to guess what it might be without reading your comment).

Answer (score 1):

You should filter your own ip address so it doesn't show up at the results. Although I am not familiar with webalizer, google analytics have this option if you go to the filters and add an exclude command for your ip adresses.